# Using PHP in a frame on a ColdFusion page

Tags: php, coldfusion, frame

My organization uses ColdFusion pages for most everything.  The administration decides the standard layout, look, and feel of every page so things look uniform across all of the organizations pages, but each department can modify certain "components" of their pages. Each of the "components" that can be modified exist as a `.cfm` file, so any changes I make must be made in those `.cfm` files.

I want to include a PHP script I made in on one of my departments pages, but obviously I cannot use two server-side scripts on the same file at the same time.  My idea is to make a frame in the `.cfm` file where the source is my PHP script like this:

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://myorgainzation/test.php" frameborder="0" />
</frameset>
```

When I do this I can view my page's source code in FireFox, click on the `http://myorgainzation/test.php` link, and view what my PHP script generates.  The problem is that the information generated by the PHP script isn't showing up in the frame like I expected it to.  In fact there is nothing there at all.

I have not used frames very often, is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frames are outdated for most practical purposes. You would be better off using a 100% height and 100% width [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: HAHA! It worked!  Thanks for helping me fight the man!  I feel empowered now... this opens up so many doors for what I can do for my department!

Comment: @typo - I think what you meant to say is that this opens so many pandora's boxes. If you act as a lone coder you will eventually compromise your entire team.

Comment: @Anthony no no, I am the only coder in my department, and I don't do anything that will in any way compromise the main site. Additionally I inform my superior what my changes will do before I make the changes that way we are all covered.